# camel redeliver : How do I retry processing a message from a certain point back

Tags: java, apache-camel

I wanted to apply re-deliver and use Dead Letter Channel. So found this very useful apache-camel FAQ [link](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-retry-processing-a-message-from-a-certain-point-back-or-an-entire-route.html). I followed the steps as mentioned in this website.

I added a little more logic, the code is available in [github](https://github.com/RakeshBhat/rb-simplecamel-example/) .

Basically, as per the FAQ, we have to split the routes, such that(as mentioned in the FAQ) the camel can handle any exception in the sub route.
Here is the code (Camel Route):

```
    @Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("mock:error")
            .logExhaustedMessageBody(true)
            .logExhausted(true)
            .logRetryStackTrace(true)
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(1000)
            .backOffMultiplier(2)
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .useExponentialBackOff());

    from("direct:start")
    .log("Dump incoming body: " + body())
    .to("direct:sub")
    .end();

    from("direct:sub")
    .errorHandler(noErrorHandler())
    .process(new SubRouteProcessor())
    .log("Dump incoming body: "+ body())
    .process(new NewSubRouteProcessor())
    .transform(body().append("Modified Data !"))
    .to("mock:result");
}
```

I wrote a simple unit test, to trigger the exception, hence the redeliver code is executed.

**Now the difficulty/problem**: The expected behavior is to do only 3 redeliver attempts, with 1000 millis delay and ExponentialBackOff.

However, the Test runs forever, keeps on doing the re-delivery with exponential delay. If I remove/comment the 2 processor calls, the code does run fine, means on exception, it does only 3 retries.

Could you please help to understand, 
1) what is wrong in this code/route?
2) what is causing code to run forever?
3) why removing these processors, it works,retry happens for 
said number of times only?

I just want - when ever the "direct:sub" throws "exception", the control goes back to "direct:start", re-try processing message from a certain point.

Thank you !!

Comment: Can you please share the code for your Processors? It seems to me that you have identified the problem correctly, it should lie within the Processors.

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri i already shared github location, can you access it?

Comment: Yes I can, I didn't see the link first time round! May I ask why you are setting  the body on the Out message? I don't see why you should need anything but In() message i.e exchange.getIn().setBody(body)

Comment: Just creating a new Message Object. And yes I agree, i could use In() as well.
http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked out your code and simply by changing getOut to getIn in both of your processors, the test passes.

Edit: My suspicion from the beginning was that your processors were somehow overriding the headers Camel set in order to do a certain amount of redelivery. In your case:

```
CamelRedelivered=true, CamelRedeliveryCounter=1, CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter=3
```

The header CamelRedeliveryCounter was not incremented when you were setting the Body on the getOut exchange. In my mind, it should and this is a bug; but maybe it is working as designed? Maybe @claus-ibsen could help with that.

Hope this helps.

R.

Comment: thank you!
Could you please add some elaborated explanation, why exchange getOut was causing redeliver into a infinite loop? where as exchange getIn didn't?
Also Exchange only implementation DefaultExchange is a immutable class.
https://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.15.0/camel-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultExchange.html#line.41

somehow the camel-2.17.1 Java Doc isn't available in above maven url.

Comment: getIn or getOut returns a Message, not an Exchange. I'm updating my response with a bit more information but don't think I have the time to investigate exactly why this is happening. It could even be a bug in Camel.

Comment: thanks again Ramin Arabbagheri, i hope @claus-ibsen could help explain the behaviour.

Comment: one related question: during the test, when direct:sub section/part of route throws exception, should the control back go to direct:start section/part of route?

Comment: In your case no, the redelivery only kick in direct:sub route. Also since you configured the errorHandler outside of your routes, for camel it will be as if you have copy pasted the errorHandler logic to both of the routes.